# C: How to fix 'Segmentation fault' when I want to open and write a file?

Tags: c

I am trying to open a file, but neither I switch the "r" to "rt" nor "at+", "fp" always return NULL. And after I input a string, the output will be a Segmentation fault. Where is the mistake I made? Please help me with that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char str[120] = {0}, strTemp[100];
    if( (fp=fopen("/User/don/Vim/code.c", "at+")) == NULL ){
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
    }
    printf("Input a string:");
    gets(strTemp);
    strcat(str, "\n");
    strcat(str, strTemp);
    fputs(str, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
 Input a string: hello
```

actual output:

```
 Cannot open file
 Input a string: hello
 Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: What do you expect your program to do right after `printf("Cannot open file\n");`. It should give up and exit, shouldn't it? Can you explain how your program avoids attempting to access the file after failing to open it?

Comment: Add `perror("fopen");` in `if` block to know why `fopen` failed

Comment: BTW: Never use `gets`, it's an insecure and deprecated function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
if( (fp=fopen("/User/don/Vim/code.c", "at+")) == NULL ){
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
}
```

by

```
if( (fp=fopen("/User/don/Vim/code.c", "at+")) == NULL ){
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
    return 0;
}
```

else you will use a null pointer after in `fputs(str, fp);`

as Jabberwocky says *gets* is dangerous because you can overflow the buffer, it is more secure to use *fgets*

of course you can also do your work in an `else` branch :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  char str[120] = {0}, strTemp[100];
  if( (fp=fopen("/User/don/Vim/code.c", "at+")) == NULL ){
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Input a string:");
    fgets(strTemp, sizeof(strTemp), stdin);
    strcat(str, "\n");
    strcat(str, strTemp);
    fputs(str, fp);
    fclose(fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` leaves the newline into the buffer, so output of this program won't be the same as the program in the question.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer does help me find the mistake

Comment: Another important thing: if `fgets` gets EOF, it will return NULL and might not modify the buffer (I suppose this depends on the implementation). So you have to check `fgets` return value to be 100% safe, though initialising the buffer with zeros before calling `fgets` is probably safe too. And I did just test this on OSX, hitting ctrl-d makes `fgets` return NULL and not modify the buffer.

Comment: @hyde yes, I just I did the minimal changes, the O.P. did not check the result of _gets_ too